# How can I get my incoming mail working again?

Tags: postfix, email-server, email-bounces, virtualmin

We are using webmin and virtualmin the emails have been working great over the last couple of weeks using virtualmin but today suddenly they have stopped.
I get this in my mail log:

```
Jul 1 13:15:03 server1 postfix/pickup[18805]: 4A7276E093D: uid=0 from=
Jul 1 13:15:03 server1 postfix/cleanup[19038]: 4A7276E093D: message-id=20190701131503.4A7276E093D@server1.domain.uk 
Jul 1 13:15:03 server1 postfix/qmgr[18806]: 4A7276E093D: from=<root@server1>, size=2851, nrcpt=1 (queue active) 
Jul 1 13:15:03 server1 postfix/smtp[19040]: 4A7276E093D: to=<root@server1>, orig_to=, relay=none, delay=0.13, delays=0.08/0.05/0.01/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for server1 loops back to myself) 
Jul 1 13:15:03 server1 postfix/cleanup[19038]: 6B56D6E0945: message-id=20190701131503.6B56D6E0945@server1.domain.uk Jul 1 13:15:03 server1 postfix/bounce[19041]: 4A7276E093D: sender non-delivery notification: 6B56D6E0945 
Jul 1 13:15:03 server1 postfix/qmgr[18806]: 6B56D6E0945: from=<>, size=4774, nrcpt=1 (queue active) 
Jul 1 13:15:03 server1 postfix/qmgr[18806]: 4A7276E093D: removed Jul 1 13:15:03 server1 postfix/smtp[19040]: 6B56D6E0945: to=<root@server1>, relay=none, delay=0.02, delays=0.01/0.01/0.01/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for server1 loops back to myself) 
Jul 1 13:15:03 server1 postfix/qmgr[18806]: 6B56D6E0945: removed
```

main.cf is as follows:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/postfix.cert.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/postfix.key.pem
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = server1.domain.uk
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, server1.domain.uk, localhost.domain.uk, monster-it.uk , localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/bcc
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail-wrapper -o -a $DOMAIN -d $LOGNAME
home_mailbox = Maildir/
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
smtp_tls_security_level = dane
allow_percent_hack = no
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/postfix.ca.pem
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
```

If anyone could shed some light on this that would be good. I do get the correct response when I dig the mx record.

Comment: Please edit your question and paste your postfix config in using the code formatting (marking it with the  `{}` button). It's impossible to read it properly with the current formatting, and I can't guess which lines may have originally been commented out or not so I can't fix it for you.

Comment: Sorted. I've updated it now. We are using virtualmin but the forums are so quite no-one has responded since i posted last week.

Comment: One thing I see immediately is that the mail log talks about `root@server1`, i.e. doesn't contain the fully qualified domain name. Your postfix config does not contain the bare hostname without domain. That'd be something to test first.

Comment: Hi, Spot on got it thank you. :) not sure why that changed at all. however i'm getting this in the error log now.

Comment: {Jul  2 12:39:35 server1 postfix/smtpd[25186]: warning: unknown[45.13.39.24]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Jul  2 12:39:35 server1 postfix/smtpd[25186]: disconnect from unknown[45.13.39.24] ehlo=1 auth=0/1 rset=1 quit=1 commands=3/4
Jul  2 12:39:36 server1 postfix/smtpd[25293]: warning: unknown[45.13.39.120]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Jul  2 12:39:36 server1 postfix/smtpd[25293]: disconnect from unknown[45.13.39.120] ehlo=1 auth=0/1 rset=1 quit=1 commands=3/4

Comment: You've set it to use SASL but you've not configured any SASL provider. You should go read http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have one or more program trying to send email using only the bare hostname, without domain name - `root@server1`.

The bare hostname is not included in the configuration. To fix this, add `server1` to the `mydestination` line.